# dereferencing struct pointer to structure variable

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am having a little bit of confusion about derefrencing a structure pointer to a 
structure variable.

It will be good if I demonstrate my problem with an example.

So here I am:

```
struct my_struct{
    int num1;
    int num2;
}tmp_struct;

void Display_struct(void * dest_var){

    struct my_struct struct_ptr;

    struct_ptr = *((struct my_struct *)dest_var);

    printf("%d\t%d\n",struct_ptr.num1,struct_ptr.num2);

}

int main()
{
    tmp_struct.num1 = 100;
    tmp_struct.num2 = 150;


    Display_struct(&tmp_struct);
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I am running this example I am able to get the code to be compiled in a very clean manner and also the output is correct.

But what I am not able to get is that is this a correct way of dereferencing the structure pointer to a structure variable as we do in case of other simple 
data types like this:

```
int example_num;

void Display_struct(void * dest_var){

    int example_num_ptr;

    example_num_ptr = *((int *)dest_var);

    printf("%d\t%d\n",struct_ptr.num1,struct_ptr.num2);
}

int main()
{
    example_num = 100;


    Display_struct(&example_num);
    return 0;
}
```

Here we can dereference the int pointer to int variable as it is a simple data
type but in my opinion we can't just dereference the structure pointer in similar manner to a structure variable as it is not simple data type but a complex data type or data structure.

Please help me in resolving the concept behind this.

Comment: why couldn't you dereference a pointer-to-structure? what would be the point in a pointer that you can't access the underlying object of?

Comment: do you mean something like that: https://ideone.com/lduzh0 ?

Comment: What's the actual problem here ? BTW The second example is wrong, you try to printf `struct_ptr.num1` but there is no `struct_ptr` in the second example.

Comment: `struct_ptr` and `example_num_ptr` are both not pointers.  So I believe that you have a misunderstanding of what your program is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that you have to guarantee that the passed `void*` points to a variable of the correct struct type. As long as it does, everything will work fine.

The question is why you would use a void pointer and not the expected struct, but I assume this function is part of some generic programming setup, otherwise it wouldn't make sense to use void pointers.

However, if you would attempt something "hackish" like this:

```
int arr[2] = {100, 150};
Display_struct(arr);  // BAD
```

Then there are no longer any guarantees: the above code will compile just fine but it invokes undefined behavior and therefore may crash & burn. The struct may contain padding bytes at any place and the code also breaks the ["strict aliasing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) rules of C.

(Aliasing refers to the rules stated by the C standard chapter 6.5 Expressions, 7§)

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking up a problem where there isn't any. A `struct`-type (alias an *aggregate* data type) is technically not very different from any other type.

If we look at things on the lower level, a variable of any type (including a `struct` type) is just some number of bits in memory.

The type determines the number of bits in a variable and their interpretation.

Effectively, whether you dereference a pointer-to-`int` or a pointer-to-`struct`, you just get the chunk of bits your pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

In your main function, you have `struct  tmp_struct`. It is not a pointer. But it is fine, because you pass `address` of `tmp_struct` to the function `void Display_struct(void * dest_var)`.

Then function take the input argument, your pointer(void*). It hold the address of 'tmp_struct`.

Then inside the function you are de-referencing correctly.

```
struct_ptr = *((struct my_struct *)dest_var);
```

you deference `void*` to `struct my_struct` type. Your de-referencing correct, because you pass same type object. Otherwise it will cause run time issues.

No matter how complex your data type or data structure, de-referencing should work fine.

But if input arg type is void* make sure to pass `struct my_struct` to function.